# Can you please help me understand the phrase "her way out of a paper bag"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Happy New Year!
I am learning English watching shows. One of them is Fear the Walking Dead.
Here is a quote from subtitles of first session part one, a scene where Maddy is talking to Artie somewhere at begining:

> Travis stayed, so Stacy's gonne take his classes. Ah, well, Stacy
>   can't teach her way out of a paper bag.

I do not clearly understand second sentence. What is "her way out of a paper bag"? Could you please rephrase in more simple way?

Comment: See: [What does “X his way out of a paper bag” mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29669/what-does-x-his-way-out-of-a-paper-bag-mean)

Comment: Thank you! I have not found that because I did not know which words to google. :-( First I googled "teach her way out". So I could not found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic phrase that is being referenced is

> [couldn't punch their way out of a paper bag](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/way_out_of_a_paper_bag)

it means they don't know what they are doing, that they are incompetent.

The BrE equivalent is

> [could not organize a piss up in a brewery](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/couldn't_organise_a_piss-up_in_a_brewery)